# Programmatically send to front/back elements created from interface builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder, z-axis

In interface builder, there are layout options to send to back or send to front any elements such as `UIButton`, `UIImage`, `UILabel` etc...

Now, I would like to do the same at runtime, programmatically.

Is there an easy way to do that?

I do not want to create different views, just update the z-axis.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

There are a number of methods of `UIView` that allow you to modify the view hierarchy.

- [`bringSubviewToFront:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubview)
- [`sendSubviewToBack:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622618-sendsubview)
- [`insertSubview:atIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622538-insertsubview)
- [`insertSubview:aboveSubview:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622570-insertsubview)
- [`insertSubview:belowSubview:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622598-insertsubview)
- [`exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622448-exchangesubview)

Since your views are already inserted into your superview, you could easily call `bringSubviewToFront:` once for each view in whatever order you like.

Comment: Are you saying that I can't directly send a UIButton to front/back? I have to create a view and add it to that view. Then use the methods above? If so, Is the controller class the place to create such a view?

Comment: A UIButton is a subclass of UIView. Just call: [[myButton superview] bringSubviewToFront:myButton];

Comment: Just to clear a small doubt I had: if you insert a subview that's already in the view hierarchy, the OS will only move its position. So, inserting as long as the view exists will not cause any overhead.

Comment: "call `bringSubviewToFront:` once for each view in whatever order you like" thats a really trick. Good one.

Answer (score 43):

You could use:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myButton];
```