# Bring UIButton to front layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know there is a way of bringing a subview to the front of the hierarchy. However is there a way of bringing a button that i have placed on a story and calling a function that will make that button the top layer so its not hidden by any other elements that are added that aren't in the story board.

Thanks,

Comment: A button is a subview as well.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1054946/1593583

Answer (score 13):

I am late for this question, but not too late to answer it by Swift 3

### Swift 3

```
 view.bringSubview(toFront: theButton)
```

Answer (score 6):

A UIButton is a UIView, so you can call `-bringSubviewToFront:` on your button instance.

Answer (score 6):

`uiview`'s are displayed in the order they are stacked. One can change this to say were to insert the new `uiview`, which in your case is a uibutton.

One way of doing that is by creating a `IBOUtlet` of the `uibutton` and adding that button instance as a subview/newview above an existing `uiview`.

**CODE:**

`[self.view insertSubview:<new Uiview> aboveSubview:<existing uiview>];`

Also if you are not able to figure out the order of the `uiview` , then you can check that in `xcode`

- When running the project in debug mode under debug window there is a  button(highlighted in below image) **Debug View Hierarchy**, you need to click that. (highlighted in below image)

[image: Debug window tool bar]

- After that you will able to see all the `views` rendering on the screen at current instance, using this feature you will be able to understand were is your new `uiview`  in the `uiview stack order`(shown below).

[image: UI View Hierarchy]

Comment: I added a view named sideBar into view controller But that view controller is one of the tabBar Controller tabs I want move the sideBar in Front of the tabBar Controller But I can't do that here is my question link please help me to solve the problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127021/how-to-place-uiview-infront-of-view-that-is-infront-of-tabbar-and-special-tabbar

Comment: I would suggest you to check the stacking order of your uiView's and then move the ordering as required, you can refer to this So, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519141/difference-between-addsubview-and-insertsubview-in-uiview-class

Comment: It's hard to explain can you chat ? I will explain that with photo and more codes

Comment: I cant find you on stackexchange chat, https://chat.stackexchange.com/  go ahead and invite me , we can talk there

Comment: ok so If I explain the problem in the comments the link of chat will appear

Comment: the problem for me is that I have a tabBar and I want to place a view inFront of that But the problem is that I made that view in story board But I read the similar pages that If I want to do that I have to define a view in code and I didn't find that how can I place a view that made in story board in front of all things ( tab bar and views )

Comment: even with storyboard, there is a code behind that is generated for work flow what you might have created, just go through the code one step at a time & figure out were do you need to alter the code to bring corresponding view to front. you can refer to the "debugViewHierarchy" to know the stack order and update the code accordingly

Answer (score 2):

### Swift

The following works great if the view you are working with is being hidden views that are in the same view.

```
superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

In my case I had to insert my view behind some buttons.  By insert it at the zero position it was placed behind the buttons.

```
        self.view.insertSubview(self.mapView!, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem with you and a friend of mine helped me

i can bring my button to another subview using this function on your view controller where you declare your button.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(chatButton)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(button)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).